# How to use ILogger in a static constructor

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger. The function has a Run method as following:

```cs
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ExecutionContext context,
    ILogger log)
```

I have a few static helper methods, which for code visibility I structured as part of a static class. I have a static constructor in the helper class, which I'm using to initialize things.
How can I use the ILogger to write log output in the constructor? As the constructor is static, I seem not to be able to add any parameters to it, so I cannot pass the ILogger from the Run method.

What would be the best way to write log output from the static constructor?

Comment: You need to 1) make sure the logging services are available at that point, and 2) have a static reference to it somewhere

Comment: I'm using the logging services already in the static helper methods (where I'm passing the ILogger as a parameter to the helper method), which is working successfully. Since I cannot do the same in a static constructor (no parameters allowed in a static constructor), could you share how I could make a static reference to the ILogger received from my Run method? (I'm quite new to this)

Comment: This is exactly why I never use static constructors.... :-|

Comment: Just don't use a static constructor. If you must have a singleton in a static field (for whatever reason) create an instance of it up-front and initialize it later (with an instance method), but it's better to avoid the use of statics in the first place. Using static initialization for anything that's not completely trivial (i.e. non-local) is a bad idea because the order in which static initialization happens is almost impossible to control and any errors are almost impossible to handle.

Comment: I am using the static constructor to initialize a few things in my static class without explicitly needing to call a method to do so (reading config values, initialize DB connection, etc.). I believe when not making my constructor static, I would also need to make the class not static and I would need to make a new instance of this class only to call the helper methods (which are not holding any instance specific things)?

Comment: Correct. Statics, hidden dependencies and "helper methods" that rely on any kind of state are the devil's tools, wean yourself off them. You don't need to use a full-blown dependency injection framework, but moving initialization to a central place where you wire up classes explicitly, using instances, so that the order of what's being initialized and who's using what is clear, is a pathway to avoiding a lot of maintenance/debugging headaches.

Comment: I agree with the other comments here. Hidden dependencies is the bane of maintenance and testing. Make it into a service instead, that you take a dependency on.